# New Item disapear from Flatlist which one is added recently and coming back to that screen data then show automatically

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, flatlist

[image]

I'm trying to use `redux` as **local storage** and I'm trying to add **floor** as you can see in the `gif` and then trying to render in Flat list when I add a new floor and click on that floor to go to another screen and come back to that flat list where my floors are rendering the recent floor I've added disappear and when I got back to that and come back again on flat list screen then it renders automatically the recent one that disappeared. Kindly help me to figure it out what's the issue

Here is my code

**Add New Floor to existing array in redux**

```
 const handleNewFloor = () => {
    if (floorName === '') {
      Snackbar.show({
        text: 'Kindly Enter Floor Name',
      });
    } else {
      let id = uuid.v1();
      let localList = floorList;
      const params = {
        flo_id: id,
        buil_id: item && item.buil_id,
        hos_id: hos_id,
        user_id: user && user.user_id,
        flo_name: floorName,
        hos_name: name,
        buil_name: item && item.buil_name,
        is_delete: '0',
        mode: '0',
        updated_date_time: new Date().toLocaleString(),
        added_date_time: new Date().toLocaleString(),
        userName: user && user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name,
        user_id: user && user.user_id,
      };
      let allFloor = [...floorList, params];
      new Promise((rsl, rej) => {
        addFloor(allFloor, rsl, rej);
      })
        .then((res) => {
          Snackbar.show({
            text: res,
          });
          // navigation.navigate('Home');
          setUpdate(true);
          floorRef.current.close();
          setFloorName('');
          console.log(res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          Snackbar.show({
            text: err,
          });
          console.log(err);
        });
    }
  };
```

**Here is ther Flatlist code**

```
<FlatList
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          data={floors}
          extraData={floors}
          renderItem={renderFloor}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item}
        />

const renderFloor = ({item, index}) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate('Monitoring', {name, building, item});
        }}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: index % 2 === 0 ? '#F7FEFF' : '#F2F6F9',
          // margin: 0.2,
          paddingHorizontal: 2,
          paddingVertical: 15,
          flexDirection: 'row',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'space-between',
          // borderRadius: 4,
        }}>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          <MaterialCommunityIcons
            name="ruler"
            color={'lightgray'}
            size={25}
            style={{alignSelf: 'center'}}
          />

          <Text style={[styles.mediumText, {marginLeft: 10}]}>
            {item.flo_name}
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
          <Entypo name="chevron-small-right" color={'gray'} size={20} />
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };
```

Comment: What is the list rendering, where does it come from, what actions are dispatched, what changes do they make to the redux state? Maybe you can solve it by chaning keyExtractor to return item.flo_id

Comment: I was using useFocusEffect to filter floors based on building id and that's the reason this was happening.Thanks BTW